# Sum all Inserted Values in Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

Suppose, I have the following table `T1`:

```
| type | col1 | col2 |
|------|------|------|
| abc  | 0    | 0    |
| def  | 0    | 3    |
| abc  | 3    | 123  |
| def  | 0    | 5    |
| def  | 2    | 4    |
```

Periodically, some new values are inserted into `T1`. I now want to create a trigger, which populates another table `T2`, depending on the values *inserted* into `T1`.

The values to insert into `T2` can be calculated using the following pseudo code:

```
IF col1 = 0 AND col2 = 0
    A++
ELSE IF col1 = 0 col2 > 0
    B++
ELSE IF col1 > 0
    C++
```

I already created the following trigger:

```
Create TRIGGER TRI1
    ON dbo.T1
    FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dbo.T2
    SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN col1 = 0 AND col2 = 0 THEN 1 END) as 'A',
           Sum(CASE WHEN col1 = 0 AND col2 > 0 THEN 1 END) as 'B',
           Sum(CASE WHEN col1 > 0 THEN 1 END) as 'C'
    FROM INSERTED 
END
```

---

When I test it with:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.T1 VALUES ('abc',2,3)
INSERT INTO dbo.T1 VALUES ('abc',0,0)
INSERT INTO dbo.T1 VALUES ('def',0,3)
INSERT INTO dbo.T1 VALUES ('abc',0,0)
```

I get the following output:

```
| A    | B    | C    |
|------|------|------|
| NULL | NULL | 1    |
| 1    | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | 1    | NULL |
| 1    | NULL | NULL |
```

But the expected output is only 1 row per insert operation:

```
| A | B | C |
|---|---|---|
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO dbo.T1 VALUES ('abc',2,3), ('abc',0,0), ...`  one operation. `insert into ...; insert into ...;` - two

Comment: Yeap....your code does exactly what it is supposed to. It produces 1 row for every insert. Is there something different you expect? Or do you need to insert multiple rows in a single insert statement to test this?

Comment: You have 4 insert, so you have 4 different operation, and one row por insert operation. Behaviour is OK.

Comment: Maybe you want `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`? so if `T2` already have  `VALUES ('abc'` `UPDATE` T2 instead `INSERT` But I think your T2 is inclomplete doesnt seem to have an ID or something to difference.

Comment: @Mike: That solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a trigger like this,

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRI1 ON dbo.T1
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM dbo.T2
            )
    BEGIN
        UPDATE T
        SET A = Sum(CASE 
                    WHEN T.col1 = 0
                        AND T.col2 = 0
                        THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                    END)
            ,B = Sum(CASE 
                    WHEN T.col1 = 0
                        AND T.col2 > 0
                        THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                    END)
            ,C = Sum(CASE 
                    WHEN T.col1 > 0
                        THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                    END)
        FROM dbo.t1 T
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.T2
        SELECT Sum(CASE 
                    WHEN T.col1 = 0
                        AND T.col2 = 0
                        THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS 'A'
            ,Sum(CASE 
                    WHEN T.col1 = 0
                        AND T.col2 > 0
                        THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS 'B'
            ,Sum(CASE 
                    WHEN T.col1 > 0
                        THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS 'C'
        FROM dbo.t1 T
    END
END
```